# Перемешать случайным образом данные в каждой строке

Tags: excel, vba

Есть лист Excel в котором столбцы E, F, G, H. Можно ли как-то перемешать эти столбцы случайным образом?

Т.е. допустим было так:

```
ans1       ans2      ans3      ans4
Сигнала    Свистка   Салюта    Поцелуя
Сетка      План      Бредень   Динамит
шар        цилиндр   конус     пирамида
```

а стало так:

```
ans2       ans4           ans1       ans3
Свистка    Поцелуя        Сигнала    Салюта
План       Динамит        Сетка      Бредень
цилиндр    пирамида       шар        конус
```

Comment: Т.е. содержимое этих столбцов перемешать случайным образом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Макросом,  тасование Фишера — Йетса:

```
Sub Shuffle() ' Тасование столбцов целиком
    Dim Tmp As Range
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim Cols As Variant

    Cols = Array(Range("E:E"), Range("F:F"), Range("G:G"), Range("H:H"))
    For I = 3 To 1 Step -1
        J = Int((I + 1) * Rnd)
        Set Tmp = Cols(J)
        V = Tmp.Value
        Cols(J).Value = Cols(I).Value
        Cols(I).Value = V
    Next I
End Sub


Sub Shuffle() ' Тасование столбцов построчно
    Dim R As Long
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim Tmp As Variant

    R = 1
    While (Not IsEmpty(Cells(R, 5)))
        For I = 3 To 1 Step -1
            J = Int((I + 1) * Rnd) + 5
            Tmp = Cells(R, J).Value
            Cells(R, J).Value = Cells(R, I + 5).Value
            Cells(R, I + 5).Value = Tmp
        Next I
        R = R + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Чуть чуть не то что мне нужно. Мне нужно не просто столбцы целиком в случайном порядке перемешать, а данные во всех столбцах. Например есть столбцы E, F, G,H и первая строчка в этих столбцах. Нужно в этой строчке перемешать данные, также во второй и т.д.

Comment: Обновил ответ, отрабатывает до первой пустой строки в столбце `E`

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: У меня 35 тысяч строк и для таких больших данных вылезает ошибка Run-time erroe '6': Overflow на строчке R = R + 1

Comment: Должно помочь `Dim R As Long`

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо.

Comment: @slippyk, *Integer*  - "хвостик" от старых процессоров. Этот тип сейчас требует дополнительных преобразований. Используйте вседа *Long*. Да, немного больше памяти съест, но сэкономите на вычислениях. Да и подобных ошибок будет меньше.

Comment: @Kolhoznik, для больших диапазонов лучше использовать обработку в массивах, работа с объектами листа медленная.

Comment: Спасибо учту. Это разово мне было необходимо, да и желания ради этого изучать VB не было. Мне бы было легче на java парсер написать, но помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так (**перемешать целиком столбцы/строки**). Обложите свои данные случайными значениями функции `=СЛЧИС()`(или `=RAND()`) как ниже на примере (*диапазон начинается со строки 1 и со столбца A, к примеру*).

```
             0,340428874    0,076703163 0,807499996 0,919554717
0,61390529   Салюта         Свистка     Поцелуя     Сигнала
0,850945887  Бредень        План        Динамит     Сетка
0,944935893  конус          цилиндр     пирамида    шар
```

Далее нам нужно перемешать значения . Выделяем следующий диапазон

```
0,340428874 0,076703163 0,807499996 0,919554717
Салюта      Свистка     Поцелуя     Сигнала
Бредень     План        Динамит     Сетка
конус       цилиндр     пирамида    шар
```

Переходим `Главная -> Сортировка и фильтр -> Настраиваемая сортировка -> Параметры -> Столбцы диапазона -> Ok`. Далее `Сортировать по` выбираем `Строка 1`

На выходе

```
            0,810736094 0,922569869 0,208575751 0,283217144
0,928293194 Поцелуя     Салюта      Сигнала     Свистка
0,274564895 Динамит     Бредень     Сетка       План
0,516270878 пирамида    конус       шар         цилиндр
```

или так (*каждый раз по разному*)

```
            0,711695007 0,041197715 0,207870941 0,979356982
0,718814292 Свистка     Поцелуя     Сигнала     Салюта
0,259560572 План        Динамит     Сетка       Бредень
0,198317825 цилиндр     пирамида    шар         конус
```

Аналогично, если нам нужно перемешать по столбцам. Выделяем так

```
0,61390529   Салюта         Свистка     Поцелуя     Сигнала
0,850945887  Бредень        План        Динамит     Сетка
0,944935893  конус          цилиндр     пирамида    шар
```

Переходим `Главная -> Сортировка и фильтр -> Настраиваемая сортировка -> Параметры -> Строки диапазона -> Ok`. Далее `Сортировать по` выбираем `Столбец A`. На выходе

```
            0,512852582 0,603497885 0,519960084 0,219585455
0,331536762 конус       цилиндр     пирамида    шар
0,021012338 Бредень     План        Динамит     Сетка
0,666965896 Салюта      Свистка     Поцелуя     Сигнала
```

или так

```
            0,815880199 0,91124554  0,168220289 0,761347258
0,339763721 Бредень     План        Динамит     Сетка
0,0601611   конус       цилиндр     пирамида    шар
0,81674225  Салюта      Свистка     Поцелуя     Сигнала
```

Больше данных, больше вариантов.